# How to space words in a div with spans

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got trouble spacing words in a div with spans. Here is the html :

```
<div class="footer-links">
                    <span><a href="#">Suggestions</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Help</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Contact us</a></span>
                </div>
```

and the css :

```
.footer-links{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
```

JS fiddle her ==> https://jsfiddle.net/kxdnwL4k/3/

How to space words so its gets easier for users to read ?

Many thanks

Comment: Dude.  Just use the `word-spacing` property and get on with your life.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being too mean.  I'm not in the best mood today and also I literally googled "space between words property css" and got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the words are too close to read.

```css
.footer-links{
 float: right;
 margin-top: 11px;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-links">
                    <span><a href="#">Suggestions</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Help</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Contact us</a></span>
                </div>
```

I used `letter-spacing` to space out the letters a bit, and `word-spacing` to put some space between words a bit more.

Comment: I still say that its a list - but if you are not going with the list - then why have the spans around the a's?  You could just have the <a> elements and space them out in the same manner as suggested.

Comment: @gavgrif The HTML part is not my code. I copied and pasted it into my snippet. lol. I thought about that, too!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a horizontal `margin` to the `span`s. You can exclude the first one using `:not(:first-child)` or `span + span`

```css
.footer-links {
  margin: 11px 0;
  float: right;
}
.footer-links span:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-links">
  <span><a href="#">Suggestions</a></span>
  <span><a href="#">Help</a></span>
  <span><a href="#">Contact us</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: what this attribute span:not(:first-child) is doing in this case ?

Comment: "You can exclude the first one using :not(:first-child) or span + span" - it's excluding the first span. Since there is no word before the first span, no need for a margin on that word.

Comment: @Micheal Coker What this attribute does ? ==> span:not(:first-child)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to use `margin` css property to make them look more clearer?

```
.footer-links a {
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```css
.footer-links {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}

.footer-links a {
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-links">
  <a href="#">Suggestions</a>
  <a href="#">Help</a>
  <a href="#">Contact us</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You guys are using margin? You do realize there's a single CSS property named `word-spacing`, right?

Comment: @TyQ. `margin` answer is actually +1 while your `word-spacing` is -1. Anyways, mind your tone.

Comment: My point was that both work, but the `word-spacing` property is basically just less code.

Comment: @TyQ. So tell me that there's actually other, simpler way to deal with the issue then just accuse me of incompetence.

Comment: @TyQ. this solution is valid. There are dozens of ways to do just about anything with CSS, and there is usefulness to each approach.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I never said it was invalid. I just stated that it was a little *less* code with the `word-spacing` property. And yes, you are 100% correct about that. There are benefits from both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a ul for the list of links - its always best to use the right tool for the job.

Note that I have put this ul into a `<footer>` element - use a div if you are not using the HTML5 doctype. then its just a case of applying  a margin to the ul lis and you have a horizontal list with spaced out li's.

You could also get fancy and apply an "active" class to the li that reflects the current page. Then you would have a list of footer links that are spaced and in context with your page.

```css
.footer-links {
  list-style:none
}

.footer-links li {
display:inline;
margin-right:30px
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul class="footer-links">
    <li><a href="#">Suggestions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </footer>
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using li vs span ?

Comment: @GabrielD. This is formatted as a list. In your case, not much of one.

Comment: @TyQ and Gabriel D - My point was that conceptually what is being rendered is a series of related links - and as such the best (semantically correct) tool is a list. The benefit is that the HTML structure of the page reflect s the purpose of the code. Any group of elements can be rendered as a series of spans - but if its a list - call it a list and ensure correct page structure.

Comment: @gavgrif Technically, this would be in more of a `<nav></nav>` format... but, I guess you're still technically correct.

Comment: @TyQ. - a list is a list - if a series of unrelated elements were being rendered then sure - do it as a bunch of divs or spans - but if each element has a relationship to the others and is rendered in a sequential manner and especially if its a series of links that allow navigation through the page / site - then its a list. and given that this is a series of nav links that is being rendered as footer links - I am assuming its a navigational element at the bottom of hte page and therefore is still a list. IMO :)

Comment: @gavgrif Actually, a nav element is a navigation bar element, which seems to be what he could be trying to achieve. Anyways, you are completely right, it's pretty much a list, just not vertically. And the question is answered, so have a good day! :D